# How to convert an integer and double to a node?

Tags: java

I want to convert an integer and a double to a node how do you do that?

My objective here is to convert the integer and the double variables the user has entered to a node and add them in a doubly linked list.

Not sure how to go about this, I was scowering the net and nothing came up...

Code (just for fun)

```
public static void addToDBLList(int shares, double price) {         
    Node shrNode = shares;
    Node prcNode = price;
    DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();

    list.addToFront(prcNode);
}
```

Comment: What type of Objects does your doublyLinkedList take as a parameter?

Comment: Rather than posting completely useless / invalid code "just for fun", please post a question that makes sense.

Comment: Please show at least an outline of the Node class.

Answer (score 2):

you can't assign double value to Node.

```
Class Node{
   double dVal;
   int iVal;
}

Node prcNode = new Node();
prcNode.dVal = price;
prcNode.iVal = shares;
```

Lets try something like this.

Answer (score 1):

define a class containing these two data.

```
class Info{
    int shares;
    double price;
}
```

then create an instance of this class with the data of your method parameter.  then add this object intolinkedlist

```
 public static void addToDBLList(int shares, double price){       
         Info i = new Info;
         i.shares = shares;
         i.price = price;
         DoublyLinkedList list = new DoublyLinkedList();
         list.addToFront(i);
         }
```

also make sure that your DoublyLinkedList.addtoFront method can take the `Info` object as parameter.

Comment: good thinking, thats a really good way of how to do it. thank you.